# Can't convert bytes to str implicitly error?

Tags: python, encode

I'm trying to formulate a header, which includes a username and password. However I get the below stacktrace when trying to do so. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

```
# Variables used:
username = b'mister'
plus = b':'
password = b'PAssworD'

headers = {"Authorization": " Basic " + b64encode(username + plus +     password), Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

> StackTrace: headers = {"Authorization": " Basic " + b64encode(username
>   + plus + password), "Content-Type": "application/json"}
>
> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: Do it explicitly.

Comment: Or, depending on what the function you'll feed the headers into, make the whole string only bytes (including the `'basic'` part). If said function handles it correctly, that will avoid encoding, only to re-decode for sending a few calls later.

Comment: Actually the 'do it implicitly' comment helped: credentials = (username + plus + password).decode("utf-8")

Comment: @webcrew Python 3 redesigned strings/bytestrings to highlight this kind of problem: conceptually, strings always have an encoding, but bytestrings never do. Bytestrings are only for storage or transmission, never for display. Combining them without thinking about encoding is always an error.